# Как сделать скрипт добавления в друзья?

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго времени друзья! подскажите пожалуйста порядок написания скрипта, который добавляет в друзья. Регистрация у меня уже готова, база данных есть.
Какие таблицы создавать еще нужно? у меня есть вот такая таблица

```
 $sql = "
    CREATE TABLE users (
        id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
        password varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',

    mail varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',

    nikname varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',

    fio varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',

    TfN varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
    fN varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
    date_birthday DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
    hobby varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
    city varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
    phone varchar(12) NOT NULL default '',
    skype varchar(20) NOT NULL default '',
    vk varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
    tviter varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
    odnoklassniki varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
    youtube varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)";
```

Или статью посоветуйте хорошую)) В общем просто направьте меня в нужное русло.

Comment: Интересно, что мы вообще делали на заре появления Интернета, когда не было веб-ресурсов, подобно этому ([ХэшКод][1]), и при этом как-то находили ответы на такие вот вопросы...

  [1]: http://hashcode.ru

Comment: изложите свои мысли корректно, я не понимаю что вы тут написали.

Comment: @romeo радовались, что у нас зп выше :)

Comment: да что же тут непонятного? какие базы данных создавать нужно ? может объедение баз каких то нужно. Вообще по какому принципу строится добавление в друзья? Я смотрю все умные, вот только из десяти заданных мною вопросов, ответили на парочку всего нормально! все остальные это понты, типа ой да ты тупой это же элементарно. Не пишите тогда вообще если не пишете ничего полезного)Я создал пользователей как их подружить теперь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очевидно, необходимо задать каким-то образом связи между пользователями.

На мой взгляд, подошла бы отдельная таблица для связей, условно, с двумя полями "Кто связан" и "С кем связан". Оба поля должны являться внешними ключами на указанную вами таблицу (первичный ключ у вас в ней уже есть).
Итого получим связь "многие ко многим".

Таблицу можно будет расширить какими-нибудь дополнительными полями, на ваше усмотрение.

Comment: спасибо! буду пытаться своими силами! пусть у меня упадет тут уважение но, фаллас за щеку тому кто поставил мне дизлайк!))